# Matlab: Add vectors not in the same length to a matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, concatenation

Is it possible to automatically add vectors that are not in the same length together for a matrix?

i.e:

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
b = [1 2]
```

How can I make C to be:

```
c = [1 2 3 4 ; 1 2 0 0]
```

or

```
c = [1 2 3 4 ; 1 2 NaN NaN]
```

or something like that

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function like this

```
function out = cat2(a, b)

    diff = length(a) - length(b)
    if diff > 0
        b = [b, nan(1, diff)];
    else
        a = [a, nan(1, -diff)];
    end

    out = [a;b];

end
```

(but also add a check to handle column vectors too)

```
cat2([1 2 3 4], [1 2])

ans =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

This might help

```
a = [1 2 3 4];
b = [1 2];
c = a;
c(2,1:length(b)) = b;

c =

 1     2     3     4
 1     2     0     0
```

then, if you'd rather have `NaN` than `0`, you could do what Dennis Jaheruddin suggests in a comment below.

Comment: Good point Dan, I'll update my answer to incorporate (ie steal) your idea.

Comment: The `NaN` solution will also replace zeros in the original vectors which is probably not desirable. I would suggest `c(2,length(b)+1:end) = NaN`